# Exterior power respects $G$-action

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, exterior-algebra

*Basic setting*:

Let $V$ be a $k$-vector space of finite dimension and $V^*$ its dual space. Let $\bigwedge^n V$ denote the $n$-th exterior power of $V$.

Now the canonical pairing 
$$V \times V^{*} \to k, (v,v^*) \mapsto v^*(v)$$
gives rise to a pairing $P(,)$ on the exterior powers:
$$\bigwedge\nolimits^n V \times \bigwedge\nolimits^n V^{*} \to k$$
$$(v_1\wedge\dots\wedge v_n,v^*_1 \wedge \dots \wedge v^*_n) \mapsto \det (v_i^*(v_j))_{i,j}$$
This pairing is **perfect** (as one can compute on a basis).

Let $G$ be a finite group whose order is not divided by the characteristic of $k$. Let $V$ now be a $G$-set, ie. as a module over the group ring $k[G]$. (or equivalently as a representation of $G$ over the field $k$).

> **Question**: Is the induced isomorphism 
>   $$\bigwedge\nolimits^n V^* \to (\bigwedge\nolimits^n V)^*,$$
>   $$w^* \to (w \mapsto P(w,w^*))$$
>   an isomorphism of $G$-sets?

**Attempt**: For $w = w_1 \wedge \dots \wedge w_n \in \bigwedge\nolimits^n V$ and $w^* = w^*_1 \wedge \dots \wedge w^*_n$ I calculated:

\begin{align*}
P(w,g \cdot w^*) & = \det ((g \cdot w_i^*)(w_j))_{i,j} \\
& = \det (w_i^*(g^{-1}w_j)_{i,j}
\end{align*}
by the definition of the dual representation. But now I can't see why this is equal to 
$$g \cdot P(w,w^*)$$

Is this the right attempt to show that the above isomorphism respects the $G$-action? How to proceed? Thank you for your help :-)

Comment: It's probably conceptually cleaner to prove that $P(gw, gw^*) = P(w,w^*)$. This would follow from $(gv, gv^*) = (v,v^*)$, by the definition of dual representation.

Comment: @Sanchez Thanks for the quick response. Proving that $P(,)$ preserves the $G$-action is the same as saying that the induced isomorphism is a $G$-equivariant map?

Comment: Yes. It shouldn't be hard to check.

Comment: @Sanchez It is quite easy for me to prove that $P(gw,gw^*) = P(w,w*)$ for any $g \in G$, but showing that the above isomorphism is $G$-equivariant from that gives me a hard time. Let's name it $\psi$. I have to show that $\psi(g w^*) = g \psi(w^*)$, right? $\psi(gw^*)$ is the map that sends $w \in \bigwedge\nolimits^n V$ to $P(w,gw^*)$. But on the other hand $g \psi(w^*)$ is $g* P(w,w^*)$ which seems to be different, even if $P(,)$ preserves the $G$-action?

Comment: Can you write down exactly what you get for $g \psi(w^*)$, in the form of $(w \to P(-,-))$?

Comment: @Sanchez I thought it is $(w \mapsto g \cdot P(w,w^*))$?

Comment: No. $P(w, w^*) \in k$, where there is no $G$-action. If you figure out what $g \cdot (w \to P(w,w^*))$ is supposed to be, you are probably done. Hint: $\psi(w^*)$ lies in $(\wedge^k V)^*$. When I do the evaluation $(g \cdot \psi(w^*)) (w)$, it should be equal to $\psi(w^*)( ? )$?

Comment: I got it now, posted it as an answer! Thank you so much, @Sanchez!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Sanchez I got the answer:

First of all, we prove that the pairing on the exterior power of $V$ is invariant under the $G$-action:

\begin{align*}
P(gv,gv^*) & = P(gv_1 \wedge \dots \wedge gv_n, gv_1^* \wedge \dots \wedge gv_n^*) \\ 
 & = \det ((g \cdot v_i^*)(g \cdot v_j))_{i,j} \\
 & = \det (v_i^*(g^{-1} g \cdot v_j))_{i,j} \\
 & = \det (v_i^*(v_j))_{i,j} \\
 & = P(v,v^*)
\end{align*}

Since the pairing is an invariant $G$-form and perfect, the induced homomorphism is an isomorphism and **$G$-equivariant**. Let's name it $\psi: \bigwedge\nolimits^n V^* \to (\bigwedge\nolimits^n V)^*, w^* \mapsto P(-,w^*)$. Then

\begin{align*}
\psi ( g \cdot w^*)(w) & = P(w,g \cdot w^*) \\
 & = P(g^{-1} \cdot w, g^{-1} g \cdot w^*) \\
 & = P(g^{-1} \cdot w, w^*) \\
 & = g \cdot \psi(w^*)(w)
\end{align*}
where the last equality stems from the definition of the action of $G$ on the dual space $(\bigwedge\nolimits^n V)^*$.

Comment: Good job :) ${}{}$